# CSS icons with some semantic text, browsercompatibility issues

Tags: css, accessibility, css-sprites

I'm using this code to display sprite driven icons (if graphics are available only the icons should show up, for other devices the text is supposed to help):

Markup:

```
<span class="icon ok">OK</span>
```

CSS:

```
.icon { display:block; width:16px; height:16px; padding-left:40px; overflow:hidden; background:transparent url(sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; }
.ok { background-position: -16px 0px; }
```

The sprite itself is working fine in any browser, but the text shows up in Opera and Chrome for some reason because the padding in conjuction with overflow:hidden won't work as supposed.

Any ideas how this could be improved?
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of hiding images by shifting them out of sight is to use `text-indent:-9999em` or something similar. It needs to really big for Opera and ems work well as they'll scale with any change in font size. Also it's a good idea to set `line-height:0; font-size:0;` for ie which sometimes likes to add extra space. You shouldn't need the padding to hide the text if you use `text-indent`.

Answer (score 2):

Try negative text-indent instead.

```
.icon { display:block; width:16px; height:16px; text-indent: -9999px; background:transparent url(sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need just icon (16x16 box) or icon with descriptive text. Anyway, if you need just 16x16 box, you can hide text just by

```
.icon { display:block; width:16px; height:16px; background:transparent url(sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat; text-indent:-9999px; }
```